# Footer logo/text css/html

Tags: html, css, css-float, footer

I have 3 separate lines of text in footer, that are supposed to stay on the left side, and a logo that is supposed to stay on the right side. No matter what I try in CSS, text and logo do not align. It's either making 3 lines of text fit on just one line, or the logo starts below the text, instead of being in line with it, just on the opposite(right side).

This is my html code:

```
 <footer>
        <hr>
        <p>line1</p>
        <p>line2</p>
        <p>line3</p>
        
        <img class="logo-footer" src="xxx">
        
        <hr>
        
        </footer>
```

There has to be a horizontal line at the beginning of the footer and on the bottom of it.[This is the picture of what I need to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNPJM.png)

Comment: could you add your code or something to describe your expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you expect
[image]

You can learn [flex-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) by this website https://flexboxfroggy.com/

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <hr>
 
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <p>line1</p>
      <p>line2</p>
      <p>line3</p>
    </div>

    <img class="logo-footer" src="https://avatar.iran.liara.run/public/2">
  </div>
  
  <hr>
</footer>
```

Comment: I just updated my initial post to include my current code and what i am trying to achieve. Thank you so much for responses but I didn't have success yet.

Comment: @EllaJs cound you check it again

Comment: It worked! I don't know why I had to try three times but it worked! Thank you so much! I am new to this field, and studying IT for the second semester currently, this is a truly amazing website

Answer (score 0):

Use a [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or a [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/); they are much better suited to what you want to achieve. Floats are rarely useful on the modern web.

```css
body {
  margin: 1em;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 1em;
  border-top: 1px dashed #ddd;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

footer p:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
The body of the page goes here

<footer>
  <div>
    <p>footer line 1</p>
    <p>footer line 2</p>
    <p>footer line 3</p>
  </div>
  <img src="http://picsum.photos/150">
</footer>
```